# Using leftjoin to merge csv files based on multiple columns and receiving NAs

Tags: r, merging-data

I have GPS collared data of lions and giraffes for a masters project. I've had to seperate the animals into different csv and shp files due to the high volume of data. I also have multiple files for each animal where I have added columns such as the season the gps location was in or the elevation, NDVI, etc. I now want to combine all these files together and have been using RStudio and the leftjoin and tried other methods such as merge, st_join, fulljoin etc.
Example:

```r
combined_datacas <- left_join(
  waterholescas, casdatacov,
  by=c("Lat", "Lon", "Timestamp", "animal_id"))
```

Here is an example of my data from waterholecas:

```
      animal_id  Timestamp distance_to_nearest_waterhole   Lon   Lat
1       Cas 2012-04-08 02:39:00  3333.13041830703   721363.1 7166414
2       Cas 2012-04-08 06:39:00  3331.69779980209 721354.5 7166301
3       Cas 2012-04-08 10:39:00  3464.1329308895 722307.2 7166891
4       Cas 2012-04-08 14:39:00  2417.74343771813 724203.8 7167332
5       Cas 2012-04-08 18:39:00  2983.85441244622 725335.3 7168174
6       Cas 2012-04-08 22:39:00  2807.4428112668 725241.8 7167996
```

Here is an example of casdatacov:

```
animal_id Timestamp realrand type Scaled_NDVI landform    
   landcover elevation   Lon     Lat
1       Cas 2012-04-08 02:39:00        1 real      0.3186 Lower slope (flat) Natural Grassland      1032 721363.1 7166414
2       Cas 2012-04-08 06:39:00        1 real      0.3186 Lower slope (flat) Natural Grassland      1030 721354.5 7166301
3       Cas 2012-04-08 10:39:00        1 real      0.3408 Lower slope (flat) Natural Grassland      1031 722307.2 7166891
4       Cas 2012-04-08 14:39:00        1 real      0.3582 Lower slope (flat) Natural Grassland      1032 724203.8 7167332
5       Cas 2012-04-08 18:39:00        1 real      0.3378 Upper slope (flat) Natural Grassland      1033 725335.3 7168174
6       Cas 2012-04-08 22:39:00        1 real      0.3494             Valley Natural Grassland      1032 725241.8 7167996
```

Here is an example of the combined file with NAs and without:
[image: Image of r output table]

I also get this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
4: In left_join(waterholescas, casdatacov, by = c("Lat", "Lon", "animal_id",  :
  Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`.
ℹ Row 3434 of `x` matches multiple rows in `y`.
ℹ Row 139 of `y` matches multiple rows in `x`.
ℹ If a many-to-many relationship is expected, set `relationship = "many-to-many"` to silence this warning.
```

When I do this, the result table has NAs in multiple places but some rows have combined successfully. In the original files I have no NAs. When I manually look to ensure that the lat, lon, timestamp, and animal id are the same on both files that I am joining, I am able to find them but there are still `NA`s in the combined file. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Are you sure a join is the correct operation and not a `rbind`? If so, please try to make your example reproducible by sharing from 2 of your data sets a few rows of data that you think should be joined, but that result in `NA` values. (Preferably a subset where some rows work but some rows don't.) Just 5-10 rows of data from each data frame should be plenty. `dput()` is the easiest way to share sample data, `dput(waterholescas[c(1, 2, 10), ])` will create copy/pasteable R code to recreate the 1st, 2nd, and 10th row of your `waterholescas` data.

Comment: Having `NA` in some values after `left_join` means that there are rows in `waterholescas` that do not have matching rows in `casdatacov` (based on exact matches of your `by=` fields). If you believe strongly that they actually have matching data, look for spelling or case differences in your join fields.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Zoe! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have some, and I'm inferring `dplyr` and `sf`), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: When combining data imported from csv files like this, the other thing to watch is that the automated column type identification (eg Date (in MDY or DMY) vs numeric vs character) can differ between files for the same column.  Latitude and Longitude are also prime candidates for problems of this type.  That's another thing to check.  And one (of the many) reason I don't use csv or Excel files for source data storage.

Comment: Good point, @Limey. One more (perhaps significant) point is that comparison of high-precision numeric data is prone to many problems: `(0.1 + 0.05) == 0.15` counterintuitively returns `FALSE` due to how floating-point numbers are stored. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f for details. You will likely need to find a "tolerance" so that within the categorical join fields, look for a "max difference" in your numeric join fields.

Comment: @r2evans.  Another good point.  In retrospect, I'd change "the other thing to watch" to "another thing to watch"...